# stock choice -- what does that mean?

Tags: meaning

Source: [Lessons In Electric Circuits—Volume I](http://www.ibiblio.org/kuphaldt/electricCircuits/DC/DC_2.html)

Example:

> If using a Microsoft operating system such as DOS or Windows, a couple of text editors are readily available with the system. In DOS, there is the old Edit text editing program, which may be invoked by typing edit at the command prompt. InWindows (3.x/95/98/NT/Me/2k/XP), the Notepad text editor is your **stock choice**. Many other text editing programs are available, and some are even free. I happen to use a free text editor called Vim, and run it under both
>   Windows 95 and Linux operating systems.

What exactly do you think that means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That means that is the option the comes built into Windows.  Like what comes 'stock' on a new car from the factory.  In this case, what comes with the operating system and is available even if you haven't 'upgraded' by installing something fancier.

As a sidenote, notepad has its uses but if you use a text editor much you probably should upgrade--but what you should upgrade to depends on why you are using a text editor.

Comment: I think it can also mean "usual choice" and not necessary build-in.

Comment: I originally said that wasn't true--but I guess it depends on context.  If you say something like an option on a car is stock that definitely means default.  On the other hand if you say a "stock phrase" then it does mean common.

Comment: actually, on thinking a bit further, factory upgrades are still 'stock' so while my answer about what is meant in this context stands, my elaboration is misleading and I'll clean it up for posterity

Comment: Stock can refer to the "on the shelf" options.  Essentially meaning ready-made options.